# Two outlets in a series are not working

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle

I have two dead outlets. They were originally working but went out when the hair dryer was being used in one of them.  They are connected in a series from a receptacle in the dining room which has power via a cable pulled into the receptacle box.  The receptacle was replaced, still no power.  Wires were disconnected and tested still no power.  Could I have a bad (loose) connection at the working receptacle?  I just can't seem to figure this out, should be simple.  Do I need to replace the cable between the working and nonworking receptacles?

Comment: Hello and welcome to [diy.se]! Looks like you cut yourself off mid-sentence there. Feel free to [edit] your question to finish your thought. Also, please take the [tour] and read the [help] to understand how to get the best out of those willing to help you. Most importantly, please include a description of the wiring situation (as best you understand it), with pictures (they help a lot). Tell us about what trouble shooting you've done, and, if you give an idea of your electrical background, the answer can be worded to not be condescending or baffling.

Comment: Which receptacle did you replace, and when you replaced it, did you use the side-screws or the back-stabs?

Comment: Pull the receptacal you replaced from the wall and provide clear pictures of the wiring on both sides. Include pictures into the box, best you can. Label the wires (with paper labels before the pics, or digitally after you take the pics), and [edit] the pics into your post. Click the little "mountains" icon above the text entry box, then drag your images into the "drag'n drop" box.

Comment: Coming from the dining room you circuit could be protected by a GFCI. Trace the circuit around and see if it's just your two receptacles or the entire circuit.

Comment: These problems are almost never caused by a faulty wire in the wall. Usually, a poor connection, tripped GFCI, tripped breaker or poor wiring protocol.

Comment: We’re any back stabs used? It is normally the last working receptacle or first non working one. Check both sides of the wall sometimes there is another one in the chain on the other side that is the problem.

Comment: I traced it back to the last working  outlet - the hot wire that went to the non working outlets was loose in the wirenut connecting romex.  thanks

Comment: @WarrenFrizell post an expanded version of that as your answer, and I'll give you a +1 for it :)